# Spark SQL - READ and WRITE in sequence or pipeline?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a cost function for Spark SQL.
While modelling the TABLE SCAN behaviour I cannot understand if READ and WRITE are carried out in pipeline or in sequence.

Let us consider the following SQL query:

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE columnA = ‘xyz’;

Each task:

1. Reads a data block (either locally or from a remote node)
2. Filter out the tuples that do not satisfy the predicate
3. Write to the disk the remaining tuples

Are (1), (2) and (3) carried out in sequence or in pipeline? In other words, the data block is completely read (all the disk pages composing it) first and then it is filtered and then it is rewritten to the disk or are these activities carried out in pipeline? (i.e. while reading the (n+1)-tuple, n-tuple can be processed and written).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging I found out that Spark SQL uses a so called "volcano style pull model".
According to such model, a simple scan-filter-write query whould be executed in pipeline and are fully distributed.

In other words, while reading the partition (HDFS block), filtering can be executed on read rows. No need to read the whole block to kick off the filtering. Writing is performed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you submit a job, first thing spark does is create DAG (Directed acyclic graph) for your job.

After creating DAG, spark knows, which tasks it can run in parallel, which task are dependent on output of previous step and so on.

So, in your case, 
Spark will read your data in parallel (which you can see in partition), filter them out (in each partition).
Now, since saving required filtering, so it will wait for filtering to finish for at least one partition, then start to save it.

Comment: So, according to your answer, given a single task, its computing time can be estimated by TimeRead+TimeProcessing+TimeWrite (in sequence, no pipeline). TimeRead is the time spent for reading its partition, TimeProcessing for filtering it, and TimeWrite for writing the result on local disk. Am I correct?